# Result is XXXXXXXXXXXX for Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, system-verilog

I'm currently doing a project, and I can't find the reason when my result is XXXXXX which is error. The code run smoothly when I test, but when I want to see the result, it comes out something I can't understand.

Here's my code :

```
module cu_dpu_combine(clk,start,X,Y,W,Z,result);
input clk, start ;
input [7:0] X,Y,W,Z; 
output [13:0] result ;

wire Sel_1,Sel_0, ld ;
wire [1:0] op;

cu u1(clk,start,Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op);
dpu u2(X,Y,W,Z,clk,ld,op,Sel_0,Sel_1,result);


endmodule

module cu(clk,start,Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op);

input clk, start ;
output Sel_1,Sel_0 ;
output ld ;
output [1:0] op;

reg Sel_1 , Sel_0;
reg ld;
reg [1:0] op;

reg [3:0] next_state ;
reg [3:0] present_state;

parameter [3:0] s0=0, s1=1, s2=2, s3=3, s4=4, s5=5, s6=6, s7=7, s8=8, s9=9, s10=10 , s11=11;

// next state logic
always@(present_state, start)
begin
case(present_state)
    s0: if(start == 0)
            next_state = s0 ;
         else 
            next_state = s1 ;
    
    s1: next_state = s2 ;   //result = X
    s2: next_state = s3 ;   //result = result + X
    s3: next_state = s4 ;   //result = result - Y
    s4: next_state = s5 ;   //result = result - Y
    s5: next_state = s6 ;   //result = result + W
    s6: next_state = s7 ;   //result = result + W
    s7: next_state = s8 ;   //result = result + W
    s8: next_state = s9 ;   //result = result + W
    s9: next_state = s10 ;  //result = result - Z
    s10: next_state = s11 ; //result = result - Z
    s11: next_state = s0 ;  //result = result - Z
    default : next_state = s0;
    endcase
end
///////////////////////////////
//the D flip-flops (register)
///////////////////////////////
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    present_state <= next_state;
end
///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////
//output logic
///////////////////////////////

always @(present_state)
begin
    case(present_state)
        s0: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b00000 ;   //initial condition
        s1: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b00110 ;   //form X 
        s2: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b00100 ;   //add X
        s3: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b01101 ;   //subtract Y
        s4: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b01101 ;   //subtract Y
        s5: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b10100 ;   //add W
        s6: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b10100 ;   //add W
        s7: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b10100 ;   //add W
        s8: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b10100 ;   //add W
        s9: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b11101 ;   //subtract Z
        s10: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b11101 ;  //subtract Z
        s11: {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b11101 ;  //subtract Z
        default : {Sel_1,Sel_0,ld,op} = 5'b00000;
    endcase
end
        
endmodule


module dpu(X,Y,W,Z,clk,ld,op,Sel_0,Sel_1,result);
input [7:0] X,Y,W,Z;
input Sel_0,Sel_1;
input clk;
input ld;
input [1:0] op;

output [13:0] result;
reg [13:0] result;  //14bit
reg [13:0] ar_out ;  //14bit

wire [13:0] mux_out ;  //8bit

//selection for output of multiplexer
assign mux_out = (Sel_1==1) ? ((Sel_0==0) ? W : Z) : ((Sel_0==0) ? X : Y);

//alu
always @(*)
begin 
case(op)
    0: ar_out = mux_out + result ;
    1: ar_out = result - mux_out ;
    2: ar_out = mux_out ;
    3: ar_out = 8'b0 ;
endcase
end

//register

always @ (posedge clk)
begin 
if(ld)
    result <= ar_out ;
end

endmodule
//2X-2Y+4W-3Z
```

Here's my testbench code.

```
module testbench;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg start;
reg [7:0] X;
reg [7:0] Y;
reg [7:0] W;
reg [7:0] Z;

// Outputs
wire [13:0] result;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cu_dpu_combine uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .start(start), 
    .X(X), 
    .Y(Y), 
    .W(W), 
    .Z(Z), 
    .result(result)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 0;
    start = 0;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    W = 0;
    Z = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
    
    // Add stimulus here
    start=0 ;
    X =64 ; Y=64 ; W =64 ; Z= 64 ;
    repeat(2) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    
    X =128 ; Y=128 ; W =128 ; Z= 128 ;
    repeat(1) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    X =255 ; Y=255 ; W =255 ; Z= 255 ;
    repeat(1) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    
    $stop ;
end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to toggle the clock signal in the testbench.  Currently, `clk` is always 0.  Add this to the `testbench` module after the end of the `initial` block:

```
always #5 clk = ~clk;
```

With that change, I see the `results` signal become known (the X's disappear).

Running demo on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/rLk7).

Here is the complete testbench code:

```
module testbench;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg start;
reg [7:0] X;
reg [7:0] Y;
reg [7:0] W;
reg [7:0] Z;

// Outputs
wire [13:0] result;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cu_dpu_combine uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .start(start), 
    .X(X), 
    .Y(Y), 
    .W(W), 
    .Z(Z), 
    .result(result)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 0;
    start = 0;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    W = 0;
    Z = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
    
    // Add stimulus here
    start=0 ;
    X =64 ; Y=64 ; W =64 ; Z= 64 ;
    repeat(2) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    
    X =128 ; Y=128 ; W =128 ; Z= 128 ;
    repeat(1) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    X =255 ; Y=255 ; W =255 ; Z= 255 ;
    repeat(1) @(posedge clk) ;
    start=1 ; @(posedge clk) ;
    start = 0 ;
    repeat(12) @(posedge clk) ;
    
    $finish;
end

    always #5 clk = ~clk;
endmodule
```